# How to check whether an entity with the same key value for {'id'} is being tracked by DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, change-tracking

I think the question is self explanatory:

**How to check whether an entity with the same key value for {'id'}  is being tracked?**

for example:

```
var blog = anotherDbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).Find(...);

dbContext.ChangeTracker.AttachGraph(blog, node => {
   if (node.Entry.State == EntityState.Detached) {
       //how do I check, whether there is already an entity with the same key as node.Entity
       node.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; //this might throw InvalidOperationException
   }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for exists (for instance, as part of the `Find` method), but unfortunately not exposed publicly (for some unknown reason they think it won't be useful for them and let just throw exceptions when it happens).

But since EF Core code is open source, it's not hard to extract a custom extension method which uses similar approach as the internal implementation of `Find` (it's true that you can search `Local` property of the `DbSet`, but it is hard to get to it with non generic code, is inefficient and has to deal with unknown key property names(s) and type(s) - all that already handled by the internal code). The method is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class ChangeTrackerExtensions
    {
        public static object FindTracked(this DbContext context, object entity)
        {
            var entityType = context.Model.FindRuntimeEntityType(entity.GetType());
            var key = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
            var keyProperties = key.Properties;
            var keyValues = new object[keyProperties.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i++)
                keyValues[i] = keyProperties[i].GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
            var stateManager = context.GetService<IStateManager>();
            return stateManager.TryGetEntry(key, keyValues)?.Entity;
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem with that is the usage of a code marked as part of the "internal infrastructure, so you'll get some warnings. Just ignore or suppress them. The above code works in EF Core 3.x and EF Core 5.x, and could/should be adjusted if something is changed in some future EF Core version. If you ask me, rather than wasting time for creating code analyzers to show such warnings, they'd better expose the missing and useful functionality like this. Anyway, it is what it is, and we should work with what they give to us.

Comment: Nice answer, debugged EF Core several hours to find better solution, unfortunately we have to do that in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Each table within a context is a `DbSet<TEntity>`. This has a propery `Local`. Here are all entities, that are loaded are available. You can search for an entity without generating a call to the real server.

```
var objFromLocalLinqQuery = dbContext.Blogs.Local.Find(...);
```

Then you could get the `EntityEntry<>` by calling

```
var entity = context.Entry(objFromLocalLinqQuery);
var state = entity.Entry.State;
```